# I want Swipe to delete only to work on case:0 not case:1 - Segmented Control

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app i have swipe to delete in my segmented control and it works by showing two different tableviews, but i only want to have the swipe to delete to work in my case 0, and not in my case 1 (because case 1 contains other users data that the currentuser cant be able to delete.

How can i accomplish this?

This is my swipe to delete and report code :

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, nil) in
        Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.message[indexPath.row].messageID).setValue([])                
    }

    let report = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Report") { (action, view, nil) in

        let areUSureAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to report?", message: "This will block this user from message you.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)  
        areUSureAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

            Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.message[indexPath.row].messageID).setValue([])

            let blockedPost = ["timestamp" : [".sv" : "timestamp"]]
            Database.database().reference().child("blocked").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.message[indexPath.row].fromID).setValue(blockedPost)
        }))

        areUSureAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
            //dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))

        self.present(areUSureAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
    report.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.8918681279, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, report])
}
```

i have tried calling

```
switch(mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {

    case 0:

    //do all the report and swipe in here

    case 1:

        break


    default:
        break
    }
```

But i think im doing this wrong.. Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

The swipe actions are created dynamically so check the `selectedSegmentIndex` in `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`. If the index is not `0` `nil` is returned that means no swipe actions are shown.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    guard mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 else { return nil }

    let delete = ...
```

Comment: Oh yes thanks, havent thought of that! But this only removes the report button in segment case 1 (the delete button is still there?)